# Java Layout Confusion

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager

I am trying to understand java layouts .But my frame  did not get displayed.What am  I doing wrong. Could you please help?

```
public class NewClass {
      NewClass(){
          JFrame f=new JFrame();
          JPanel jPanelcolor=new JPanel();
          JPanel jPanelLayout=new JPanel( new GridLayout(3,3));
          JTextField fieldred=new JTextField();

         JSlider jsred=new JSlider();
         JSlider jsgreen=new JSlider();
         JSlider jsblue=new JSlider();
         jPanelLayout.add(new JLabel("Red"));
         jPanelLayout.add(jsred);
         jPanelLayout.add(fieldred);
         f.getContentPane().add(jPanelcolor, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         f.getContentPane().add(jPanelcolor, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
         f.setVisible(true);
     }

     public static void main(String[]args){
         new NewClass();
     }
```

Comment: +1 for posting what is almost an SSCCE. You should learn to format (indent) your code, though. Every IDE has a simple shortcut that does it all for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two main problems are that

- you're adding the same `jPanelcolor`, containing nothing, twice in the same frame content pane
- you don't call `pack()` before making the frame visible, to make it have the most appropriate dimension based on the components it contains.

Another problem is that you don't respect the [Swing threading rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: Thanks a lot  you are right .is it any difference writing the code like this way or extending jframe.Because in  that article that i was following writer extends jframe